# what i have to do when string named like a numerical value

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

Have some json

```
 "car": {
                "0": "bentley cont",
                "1": "2.5",
                "2": "2015"
            }
```

What i have to do for work with it. How correctly realize this.

[image]

Comment: First, the solution is provided below in an answer, second i would ask the server to change the format, this names doesnt means anything for the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this if you are using Jackson:

```
   @JsonProperty("0")
    private String _0;
    @JsonProperty("1")
    private String _1;
    @JsonProperty("2")
    private String _2;
```